TCustomTransparentControl is not transparent
I'm trying to use TCustomTransparentControl, but it is not transparent. When creating one with :
TTransparentControl = class(TCustomTransparentControl)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;


constructor TTransparentControl.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle + [csAcceptsControls, csClickEvents];
  InterceptMouse := True;
  Width := 150;
  Height := 150;
end;

procedure TTransparentControl.Paint;
begin
  inherited;
  Canvas.TextOut(10, 10, 'I am here');
end;

// In button click
panel := TTransparentControl.Create(Self);
panel.Parent := Self;
panel.Left := 100;
panel.Top := 100;
panel.Visible := True;

It just takes the color of the parent form and hides the controls underneath it.
How am I supposed to let the controls underneath be displayed through the transparent control ?

And Canvas.TextFlags doesn't contain ETO_OPAQUE?

It does, the canvas values are the default so the text is black on white. It's just there to make sure the control does exist.

It is transparent. All controls underneath are visible for me (D10.4).

@Dżyszla can you provide a full code sample ?

@Arcus 1. Create new project (Win32), 2. Put some WinControl (button, combo) on form on point 120,120. 3. Assign Your code on click. 4. Run, click - I still see 'I am here' and other components on form (but can't click on its). Nothing more.

That's exactly what I did to test this. D10.3 though.
